2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #4 on Mathematica has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Congratulations to new moderations C.E. and xzczd on your election and thank you existing moderators for your continued service.
